# Boton cerrar JavaFx

Tags: javafx

```
@FXML
private void closeAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Trato de hacer el boton cierre en JavaFx, pero me arroja un error.

Comment: Cual es error que te esta dando?

Comment: Logre arrelgarlo solo le quite el ActionEvent :    @FXML
    private void handleExit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

Answer (score 3):

Para cerrar la ventana yo utilizo el siguiente codigo:

```
public static void cerrarVentana(ActionEvent e) {
Node source = (Node) e.getSource();     //Me devuelve el elemento al que hice click
Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();    //Me devuelve la ventana donde se encuentra el elemento
stage.close();                          //Me cierra la ventana
}
```

y luego lo implemento en mi botón Cerrar:

```
@FXML
private void btnCerrar_Click(ActionEvent e) {
    cerrarVentana(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Stage.close() no necesariamente termina la aplicación**

El problema de tratar de cerrar una aplicación de javafx  con `Stage.close()` es que si hay más de una ventana ; solo va a cerrar esa ventana . Si hay más ventanas la aplicación no se cerrará . Para salir de la aplicación  está `Platform.exit()` que terminará con la aplicación ([clase Platform javafx 11](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html)), cerrando todas las ventanas .  Y , además quizá quiera una confirmación del usuario para no cerrar la  aplicación accidentalmente o para advertir que hay alguna tarea ejecutándose . Para eso están los diálogos.Si se utiliza `System.exit(0)` se puede perder la oportunidad de advertir al usuario o tener un problema de multithreads si hay otro hilo ejecutándose.Aquí hay un ejemplo de ese comportamiento .Solo la ventana principal puede cerrarse a sí  sola  y cerrar la ventana secundaria (de estar abierta la o las ventanas secundarias ) porque el botón cerrar ventana de javafx y el de la ventana que el sistema operativo otorga ejecutan `Stage.close()` y `Platform.exit()` previo aviso de la alerta tipo `Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION` si se presiona sobre `ButtonType.OK` que en su texto aparece *aceptar* (en nuestro idioma ) . la ventana secundaria puede cerrarse a si misma , pero no puede cerrar la aplicación porque el botón cerrar del sistema operativo solo se llama  el método `Stage.close()`

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static void stage2() {
        Stage stage2 = new Stage();
        stage2.setTitle("ventana secundaria");
        stage2.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(), 640, 480));
        stage2.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Atención ");
        alert.setContentText("desea salir de la aplicaión ?");

        Button closeButton = new Button(" cerrar aplicación");
        Button addStage = new Button("abrir ventana cecundaria");
        HBox hBox = new HBox(addStage, closeButton);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        // cierra la aplicaión y el programa previa confirmacion de alert 
        closeButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            alert.showAndWait();
            if (alert.getResult().equals(ButtonType.OK)) {
                stage.close();
                Platform.exit();
            }

        });
        // lanza la segunda ventana 
        addStage.setOnAction(e -> stage2());
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 640, 480);
        stage.setTitle("ventana principal");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        // cierra la aplicaión y el programa previa confirmacion de alert 
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            alert.showAndWait();
            if (alert.getResult().equals(ButtonType.OK)) {
                stage.close();
                Platform.exit();
            }

        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch();

    }

}
```

alerta de confirmación para terminar la app
[image: cerrar app javafx]