# JavaFX: al cerrar ventana desde el icono X de la ventana no se lee el codigo que contiene el botón Salir

Tags: botón, javafx, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy creando una GUI con JavaFX. He programado el botón "Salir" para que me efectúe una serialización del ArrayList con el que estoy trabajando y este funciona bien. El problema es que  si salgo desde el icono de cerrar de la propia ventana entonces no me lee el codigo del botón "Salir" Como poddría solucionarlo?

```
 @FXML
    void onActionSalir(ActionEvent event) {

        carpetaLogin = d_i_e.getCarpetaLogin();

        ArrayList<Contrasenia> arrayListado = objConces.getConcesionario();

        imprimirArrayL(arrayListado);

        ClaseAccesoria.guardarObjeto(arrayListadoContra, carpetaLogin, "/ficheroSerializarArray.rpz");

        Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
        Stage escenario = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        escenario.close();
    }
```

Comment: ¿No te conviene mas sobre-escribir el método [`stop()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop--)?.

Comment: Exacto. La solución pasa por ahí. Solo he necesitado llevarme usando el esquema Singleton el ArrayList a serializar y la ruta hasta la clase donde puedo implementar el metodo stop().

Answer (score 1):

**Cerrar ventana gatillando `WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST`**

[image: close window javafx]

Debe tener en cuenta que `Stage.Close()` no cierra necesariamente la aplicación . Para eso esta `Platform.exit()` . Aquí hay un ejemplo en esta respuesta [Botón cerrar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/529042/69550) .

Note que el botón close no llama directamente el método `Stage.close()` sino que gatilla el evento estático `WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST`

```
close.setOnAction((t) -> {
    stage.fireEvent(new WindowEvent(stage, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST));
    });
```

y lo que hace esta definido en :

```
 stage.setOnCloseRequest((t) -> {
       
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.get()==ButtonType.OK) {
          
            stage.close();
            
        }else{t.consume();}
        
    });
```

Este es un ejemplo en una sola clase que puede probar
**App.class**

```
public class App extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    var alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    var close = new Button("salir de la aplicación");
    close.setOnAction((t) -> {
        stage.fireEvent(new WindowEvent(stage, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST));
    });

    var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(close), 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    stage.setOnCloseRequest((t) -> {

        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {

            stage.close();

        } else {
            t.consume();
        }

    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

}
```